# Can't redirect/connect to Identity Server 4 via MVC App - Docker ASP.NET Core 3.1 (IDX20803)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a Docker Linux server (running Ubutnu 18) with a containerized Identity Server, and a containerized mvc app from one of the quickstarts that does a `hybrid` flow.  However, when both these containers are running, I get a `IDX20803 Socket IO Exception`.  It seems as though no matter what I change the `authority` property, it doesn't work.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        //options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = "http://mylinuxserver.co.uk:8888"; // ids on p:8888
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.Scope.Add("web_api");
    });
}
```

If you run the mvc app in a container locally, and point the `authority` to `http://mylinuxserver.co.uk:8888` with ids running on the server, the redirect works.  If you run both mvc and ids in containers locally, it works providing you use your host ip and not `localhost`.

I don't understand what the issue is because I have always pointed the `authority` to the same URL and its worked in the pass with apis when both have been running on my Linux server.

**EDIT**

Identity server options:

```
options.IssuerUri = "http://mylinuxserver.co.uk:8888"; 
options.PublicOrigin = "http://mylinuxserver.co.uk:8888";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get *http://yourdomain.com/.well-known/2openid-configuration* and check *issuer* value. you should use issuer's value as `authority` in your clients.

If it resolves your problem, you we'll be able to change issuer using `PublicOrigin` option.

Comment: Thanks, apoligies, I should have mentioned that I changed them already (see my edit) and it still didn't work.

Comment: Your application can't fetch IdentityServer configuration when you publish that. I think your IdentityServer domain is not reachable from your Mvc-application's container.

Comment: The `issuer` value even before I set the `options` above has always been the same: `http://mylinuxserver.co.uk:8888`.  If my domain is not reachable, would you any idea how to debug/rectify this?  I so confused as its worked in the past when I set the `authority` for a webapi to the above `url`. Also, if I run ID server and mvc app both locally in containers and set the `authority` to my machine's IP, it does indeed reach ID server.

Comment: I don't have an efficient way, by you can add an endpoint and call it, in that action call your domain and return it's response as your Action response.